# How to use JSON instead of XML in Acumatica Web Services

Tags: acumatica

I understand that Acumatica Web services uses XML and SOAP, but our project requires JSON format to and fro integrating with a Ruby-based web service. How can we use JSON?

Answer (score 1):

In 6.0 version (coming soon) will be added rest interface to web service API. You should wait.